# _OBJC_CLASS_$_RscMgr Linker error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

Please excuse any minor mistakes, being my first question...
Feedback still appreciated though.

I've been trying to use a Redpark cable, in order to communicate between an iPhone and an Arduino (Mini Arduino Pro). The project has failed to build with my coding.
I've searched around for days for a solution, but what has worked for others hasn't worked for me.
This is my error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RscMgr", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

However, I have found that this line of code has been the problem factor. (As in, if it is removed, the project build will succeed, but will not work.)

> Inside ViewController.m -(void)viewDidLoad
>
> `rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];`

Frameworks ("Link Binary With Libraries"): ExternalAccessory, UIKit, MediaPlayer, CoreGraphics, Foundation.

> ViewController.h (With unnecessary stuff removed)
>      `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
>       #import "RscMgr.h"
>
>       @interface ViewController : UIViewController <RscMgrDelegate> {
>
>       RscMgr *rscMgr;
>
>       }
>
>       @property (nonatomic, retain) RscMgr *rscMgr;
>
>       @end`

---

> ViewController.m (With unnecessary stuff removed)
>       `#import "ViewController.h"
>
>       #import "RscMgr.h"
>
>       @implementation ViewController
>
>       @synthesize rscMgr;
>
>       - (void)viewDidLoad
>
>       {
>
>       [super viewDidLoad];
>
>       rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
>
>       [rscMgr setDelegate:self];
>
>       }
>
>       -(void) cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol{
>
>       [rscMgr setBaud:9600];
>
>       [rscMgr open];
>
>       }
>
>       @end`

---

Links to [RscMgr.h](https://github.com/mjfreshyfresh/shocker-iphone-test/blob/master/redparkSerial.h)
and [redparkSerial.h](https://gist.github.com/migueldeicaza/1873510/raw/7d50dbfc77ddda5101dfd0a54983a5c0c4043ba0/RscMgr.h)

There are no .m files for both redparkSerial.h and RscMgr.h

Comment: You need to link against the static library or framework providing the `RscMgr` class, in much the same way you link against system frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error.  You are referencing the library headers files correctly, so the compiler can compile the individual files into object files, but when the linker comes to join them all together into an application, it is finding that the library itself is not present.  You need to add the library itself to your project.  The headers only describe the interface to it, they don't include the library itself.

To do this in recent versions of Xcode, you can usually just drag the static library (a file ending in `.a`) into your project.  But you should really check the documentation for this library and follow its recommended installation procedure.

Comment: I do and do not understand what you are trying to explain to me. You talk about a static library, the .a file. I do not see or know where that is.

Comment: You've linked to a header file that's part of a GitHub project.  Another file in there is an `.a` file.  How did you find this library?  Are you just randomly copying code you find online or are you following a tutorial?  If you are following a tutorial, doesn't it tell you how to do this?

Comment: I have a project where I recreate something someone else has made. he gave me his whole code, project, etc. I added the two files which i didn't have into my project, the redparkSerial.h and RscMgr. So i guess you can consider what i just said to the randomly copying code example.

Comment: Does adding that `.a` file into your project solve your problem?

Comment: What I mean't to say was that he didn't have the .a file, thus i didn't either. I did a quick search and downloaded LibRscMgrUniv.a, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did a search?  Come on man, don't just copy random things you find with a search into your application.  As I already said, the `.a` file was in the project you linked to.  You didn't need to search, you already had the corresponding file right there.  If you've got a mismatched version or something, in could cause hard to find bugs in your application.  Just because it appears to work at first glance, it doesn't mean it's the right version.  Use the `.a` file that corresponds to the header file you are using, not something you've found with a search.

Comment: The GitHub wasn't where I got my files originally. My friend sent me his code via email. I was unaware at the time the GitHub I linked had the .a file I was looking for. I got the .a file I was talking about from a GitHub, probably the same one I linked.

Comment: Then in that case, ask the person who supplied you with the files to supply you with the missing the files or ask for the source of the files.  Don't blindly copy files in that you've found with a search.  You are badly screwing up here.  At least when you had the linker error it was visible.  This sort of thing can introduce bugs into your application that are very hard to find.  You really should stop and fix this properly instead of carrying on the way you are going.  You've just made things worse, not better.

Comment: Fine, fine. I'll go back and get the proper files n' such.